# Thread safety hibernate DAO layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, thread-safety, batch-processing

I have a list of Transaction objects.

```
List<Transaction> transactions;
```

I need to batch process these transactions by creating a pool of threads which update transactions concurrently.
These threads update these transactions using the same DAO class(**Spring** singleton bean) to update the transaction. I'm using **Hibernate** as **ORM**

What am I to consider to make sure my code is thread safe? I'm a bit confused.

Here's the DAO class. `SessionFactory` is also defined as a Spring bean which is then autowired to DAO class.

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Transaction update(Transaction transaction) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(transaction);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return transaction;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get much better performance look at pooling the DB connections, there are open source implementations like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) which works nicely with spring and hibernate. This is particularly import for batch processing.

Are you using the hibernate implementation of `SessionFactory`? If that is the case then it is indeed thread safe so you should be good.

Another suggestion is to look at [spring batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) which might be useful for your situation.

Update: you've already said you are using Hibernate so the `SessionFactory` should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is a bit bigger than threadsafety, you need to evoke transaction management.
The session generated by the session factory is threadlocal (spring's HibernateTransactionManager and the beanFactory that creates the sessuinFactory -for ex: AnnotationSessionFactoryBean- manages all this stuff)

So Your code is Safe ;)